# Simple calculation and store to database in ruby

Tags: ruby, database, forms

I'm trying to do a simple calculation with two submitted form variables then store all three variables in the database. Each variable is a column in my database.

E.G.

```
somedbfield = ( item_1 *  item_2 ) + 2
```

How would I upon form submit, `somedbfield`, `item_1`, `item_2` save in the Test database? all three items are being validated with `validates_numericality_of` in the model and they should all be integers. Here's just my basic code to find the test.id from the form submitted, but I don't know how to create a calculation using the form values and then submit all three values to the database:

```
class Test_Controller < ApplicationController

      def update
        @test = Test.find(params[:id])
            respond_to do |format|
          if @test.update(test_params)
            format.html { redirect_to('index', :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
            format.json { respond_with_bip(@test) }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
            format.json { respond_with_bip(@test) }
          end
        end

private

 def test_params
      params.require(:test).permit(:item_1, :item_2, :somedbfield)
 end

end
```

This is a much more simpler version of a question that I previously asked but couldn't get any answers for, so i'm trying just to simplify and work forward from there.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is your question ? Post your current code, and tell us what is the problem with it so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, your `update` method simply retrieves an instance of the model and saves it without doing anything.

To update the database, you would need to pass in the parameters to the instance and then save it:

```
    item_1 = params[:item_1]
    item_2 = params[:item_2]
    somedbfield = ( item_1 *  item_2 ) + 2
    @test.update(:item_1 => item_1, :item_2 => item_2, :somedbfield => somedbfield)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `params[:symbol]` syntax for this. You can use:

```
@test.item_1=params[:item_1]
@test.item_2=params[:item_2]
@test.somedbfield=params[:item_1]*params[:item_2]+2
@test.save
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: can you take another look since I already have a if @test.update(test_params) it doesn't work?